# Searching a string and returning only things I specify

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hopefully this post goes better..

So I am stuck on this feature of this program that will return the whole word where a certain keyword is specified.

ie - If I tell it to look for the word "I=" in the string "blah blah blah blah I=1mV blah blah etc?", that it returns the whole word where it is found, so in this case, it would return I=1mV.

I have tried a bunch of different approaches, such as,

```
text = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"
print(re.split('I=', text))
```

However, this returns the same String without I in it, so it would return

```
['One of the values, ', '1mV is used']
```

If I try regex solutions, I run into the problem where the number could possibly be more then 1 digit, and so this bottom piece of code only works if the number is 1 digit.  If I=10mV was that value, it would only return one, but if i have [/0-9] in twice, the code no longer works with only 1 value.

```
text = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"
print(re.findall("I=[/0-9]", text))

['I=1']
```

When I tried using re.match,

```
text = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"
print(re.search("I=", text))

<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02408BF0>
```

What is a good way to retrieve the word (In this case, I want to retrieve I=1mV) and cut out the rest of the string?

Comment: +1! For the record - thank you for asking an excellent question. You've said what you want, shown what you've tried, and generally demonstrated that you are willing to learn. Bravo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be to split the text into words first:

```
>>> text = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"
>>> words = text.split()
>>> words
['One', 'of', 'the', 'values,', 'I=1mV', 'is', 'used']
```

And then filter the words to find the one you need:

```
>>> [w for w in words if 'I=' in w]
['I=1mV']
```

This returns a list of all words with `I=` in them. We can then just take the first element found:

```
>>> [w for w in words if 'I=' in w][0]
'I=1mV'
```

Done! What we can do to clean this up a bit is to just look for the first match, rather then checking every word. We can use a generator expression for that:

```
>>> next(w for w in words if 'I=' in w)
'I=1mV'
```

Of course you could adapt the `if` condition to fit your needs better, you could for example use [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to check if the words starts with a certain string or [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) to check if the word matches a pattern.

Comment: Question though, what is the type of the value that is being returned?  Is it a string or a list?

Comment: @user: if there are square brackets, it's a list.

Answer (score 2):

## Using string methods

For the record, your attempt to split the string in two halves, using `I=` as the separator, was nearly correct. Instead of using `str.split()`, which discards the separator, you could have used `str.partition()`, which keeps it.

```
>>> my_text = "Loadflow current was I=30.63kA"
>>> my_text.partition("I=")
('Loadflow current was ', 'I=', '30.63kA')
```

## Using regular expressions

A more flexible and robust solution is to use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r"""
... I=             # specific string "I="
... \s*            # Possible whitespace
... -?             # possible minus sign
... \s*            # possible whitespace
... \d+            # at least one digit
... (\.\d+)?       # possible decimal part
... """
>>> m = re.search(pattern, my_text, re.VERBOSE)
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x044CCFA0>
>>> m.group()
'I=30.63'
```

This accounts for a lot more possibilities (negative numbers, integer or decimal numbers).

Note the use of:

- Quantifiers to say how many of each thing you want.

  - `a*` - zero or more `a`s
  - `a+` - at least one `a`
  - `a?` - "optional" - one or zero `a`s
- Verbose regular expression (`re.VERBOSE` flag) with comments - much easier to understand the pattern above than the non-verbose equivalent, `I=\s?-?\s?\d+(\.\d+)`.
- Raw strings for regexp patterns, `r"..."` instead of plain strings `"..."` - means that literal backslashes don't have to be escaped. Not required here because our pattern doesn't use backslashes, but one day you'll need to match `C:\Program Files\...` and on that day you will need raw strings.

### Exercises

- Exercise 1: How do you extend this so that it can match the unit as well? And how do you extend this so that it can match the unit as either `mA`, `A`, or `kA`? Hint: "Alternation operator".
- Exercise 2: How do you extend this so that it can match numbers in engineering notation, i.e. "1.00e3", or "-3.141e-4"?

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  Helped broaden my understanding a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
text = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"
l = (re.split('I=', text))
print str(l[1]).split(' ') [0]
```

if you have more than one `I=` do the above for each odd index in l sice 0 is the first one.

that is a good way since one can write "One of the values, I= 1mV is used"
and I guess you want to get that I is 1mv.

BTW I is current and its units are Ampers and not Volts :)

Answer (score 1):

With your re.findall attempt you would want to add a `+` which means one or more.
Here are some examples:

```
import re

test = "This is a test with I=1mV, I=1.414mv, I=10mv and I=1.618mv."

result = re.findall(r'I=[\d\.]+m[vV]', test)

print(result)

test = "One of the values, I=1mV is used"

result = re.search(r'I=([\d\.]+m[vV])', test)

print(result.group(1))
```

The first print is: `['I=1mV', 'I=1.414mv', 'I=10mv', 'I=1.618mv']`

I've grouped everything other than `I=` in the re.search example,
so the second print is: `1mV`
incase you are interested in extracting that.